# HTML Drop down values in php not working properly

Tags: php

I am trying to show dropdown values given in MySQL via PHP dynamically. The options are coming up properly but when selecting a value and submitting the form, the value which has two words with space is saving only the first word but not the whole word.

For Eg:

Select Cars:

The dropdown has the following taken from MySQL:

```
Volvo XC90
Saab 95
Mercedes SLK
Audi TT
```

When I select Volvo XC90 and submit the form, data gets saved to DB with a value just Volvo I don't XC90.

Not sure why it is not taking white space.

PHP code that pulls data dynamically from DB:

```
<select name="user_zone" class="form-control "> 
<?php   
    $zone_query = "SELECT * FROM zone_details ORDER BY zone ASC;";
    $zoneresult = mysqli_query($bd,$zone_query);
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($zoneresult))                                                                              
    { 
      if ($user_zone == $r['zone']) 
      {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
      } 
      else {
            $selected = '';
         }
     echo "<option ".$selected." value=".$r['zone'].">".$r['zone']."</option>";                                                                          }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not enclosing your option `value` attribute in quotes, so it is taking the first word as the value and assuming the other part is another attribute. Try this instead:

```
echo "<option $selected value=\"{$r['zone']}\">{$r['zone']}</option>";
```